# set of rbeta simulation histogram

Tags: r, histogram, normal-distribution

I am having some problems with this histogram.
I am running a certain number of beta simulations. Then I store the sum of the results into an array. Then i graph the array with an histogram, which obviously distributes as a normal curve. Now what i want to do is to take mean and standard deviation of this histagram, and graph on the top of it the corrispective normal distribution.
this is the code i got so far:

```
simulation = function (n,days,alpha,beta,limsx,limdx) {
  vec= rep(NA, n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    w=rbeta(days,alpha,beta,ncp=0)
    vec[i] = sum(limsx+w*(limdx-limsx))
  }

  hh=hist(
    vec,
    breaks=round(n/10),
    freq=TRUE,
    xlim=c(
      floor(min(vec)),
      ceiling(max(vec)),
    col="grey"
  )

  sample_mean=mean(vec)
  sample_sd=sd(vec)
  ss=sum (diff (hh$breaks)*hh$counts)

  curve(
    dnorm(
      x/(limdx-limsx),
      mean(vec),
      sd(vec),
    )*ss/(limdx-limsx),
    add=TRUE,
    col="red"
  )
}
```

As a result i obtain this [image: normal hist]

The flat line on the bottom should be my normal distribution.
Can anyone make it work and tell me what i was doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance and sorry if the question is silly: i am a beginner with R and doing my dissertation that is due soon, so i really can't go through every aspect of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just scaling!

You just have to change the `freq` parameter of `hist` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`:

```
hh=hist(
vec,
breaks=round(n/10),
freq=FALSE,
xlim=c(
  floor(min(vec)),
  ceiling(max(vec)),
col="grey"
```

)

By doing so, you plot in y-axis the density rather than the frequency (number of appearance of each bin).